# As I set HTTPS=true in package.json I get an error

Tags: reactjs, ssl, https

I am trying to run my react application in secure mode but as soon as I set HTTPS as true in package.json I get the following error. The app works just fine in insecure mode. I have also tried using custom SSL certificates but that also gives the same error. I am running the application on windows 7.

> ```
> "start": "set HTTPS=true&&react-scripts start"
> ```

```
set HTTPS=true&&react-scripts start
Starting the development server...
internal/buffer.js:944
class FastBuffer extends Uint8Array {}
RangeError: Invalid typed array length: -4095 at new Uint8Array (<anonymous>)
←[90m    at new FastBuffer (internal/buffer.js:944:1)←[39m
←[90m    at Handle.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:185:19)←[39m
    at Stream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\bagrmeg\Downloads\ignited-dashboard\node_modules\←[4mhandle-thing←[24m\lib\handle.js:120:12)
←[90m    at Stream.emit (events.js:323:22)←[39m at endReadableNT (C:\Users\bagrmeg\Downloads\ignited-dashboard\node_modules\←[4mreadable-stream←[24m\lib\_stream_readable.js:1010:12)
←[90m    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)←[39m
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! igniter@0.1.0 start: `set HTTPS=true&&react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the igniter@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\bagrmeg\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-11T14_28_53_501Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

After researching a bit about the issue, I found that it was an issue with React. You can find a detailed explanation of the issue in the following link - [[https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2759]](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2759).

My App was using React: **16.2.0** and React script: **1.1.1**. The issue stated above was fixed in the later versions of React. So, I created a new app with the latest React dependencies and it worked. The app was rendered on HTTPS.